# Bootstrap input group focus shadow

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I want an input group with one input-group-addon span on each side.

**The problem** I'm having is the focus shadow that you get when the input text is focused. By default, the two span doesn't show any focus border. What I want is to have the **text input** and the **right** span to show focus border.

I have compiled a JSfiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/g74Ep/268/

As you can see the box shadow is shown between the text input and the right span, which I don't want. How can this be solved?

I have tried positioning a white coloured absolute div over the blue border but it's a dirty quickfix and I would rather do it differently.

Thanks!

```
Ignore this
```